# How do update a specific row using checkboxes

Tags: php

I'm trying to update specific rows in a table that is built from a form. I am using checkboxes but the whole table is being updated instead of the specific row that I am filling in. I tried ISSET to see if I could get it to only update when the boxes were ticked, but that didn't work. Here's what I have (obviously not the whole code, but I can provide more as needed):

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';


// All possible parameters
$params = array(
    'Student',
    'homeroom',
    'teacher'

);

$wheres = array();
foreach ($params as $param) {

    // Is the param set?
    // If so, let's add it to our list of WHERE clauses
    if (isset($_GET[$param]) && !empty($_GET[$param])) {
        $wheres[] = sprintf("%s LIKE '%%%s%%'", $param, mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET[$param]));
    }
}

if ($db_found) {

    // Now let's make the SQL.
    $SQL = 'SELECT * FROM studentlist';

    // We only want to add the WHERE clause if we had some parameters passed
    if (count($wheres) > 0) {
        $SQL .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $wheres);
    }



    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $SQL);



    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['homeroom'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='responsibility' value='E'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='responsibility' value='G'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='responsibility' value='S'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='responsibility' value='N'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='organization' value='E'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='organization' value='G'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='organization' value='S'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='organization' value='N'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='independentwork' value='E'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='independentwork' value='G'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='independentwork' value='S'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='independentwork' value='N'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='collaboration' value='E'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='collaboration' value='G'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='collaboration' value='S'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='collaboration' value='N'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='initiative' value='E'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='initiative' value='G'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='initiative' value='S'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='initiative' value='N'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='selfregulation' value='E'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='selfregulation' value='G'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='selfregulation' value='S'>" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='selfregulation' value='N'>" . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
```

And then I have this as my update:

```
            <?php

        include 'connect.php';



        // Get values from form 
        $resp=$_POST['responsibility'];
        $org=$_POST['organization'];
        $ind=$_POST['independentwork'];
        $coll=$_POST['collaboration'];
        $init=$_POST['initiative'];
        $self=$_POST['selfregulation'];



       // Insert data into mysqli 
       $sql = "UPDATE studentlist 
       SET responsibility='$resp', organization='$org', independentwork='$ind', 
       collaboration='$coll', initiative='$init', selfregulation='$self'";

       $result=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

       // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
       if($result){
       echo "Successful";


       }

       else {
       echo "ERROR";
       }
       ?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

I understand that I have all the checkboxes named the same thing, but I'm not sure how to move away from that. And yes, I am new to this!!!!!

Comment: Gadzooks, that's a lot of echoes. You'd be a lot cleaner with <?= (or <?php echo for older PHPs w/ shortcodes disabled) and writing that in HTML, since it overwhelmingly is HTML. 
You appear to be missing any code that shows how your updates are actually passed in or where that sql is run from.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really not too sure what you mean. I added some more code if that helps, but I'm not sure how to get rid of all the echoes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to the end of your querya `WHERE` condition to upsate just the row you want, if you use for example `StudentId` as the identifier of your Student then you write :

`$sql = "UPDATE studentlistSET responsibility='$resp', organization='$org', independentwork='$ind',collaboration='$coll', initiative='$init', selfregulation='$self' WHERE StudentId='$studentId' ;`