# Update with WHERE not working?

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I cannot get my database to update when I use a WHERE statement. I'm new to all of this, but in my brain it should work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I only echoed the $stu_dent to see if it worked.

```
        <?php

include 'connect.php';

    print_r($_POST);

// Get values from form 
$resp=$_POST['responsibility'];
$org=$_POST['organization'];
$ind=$_POST['independentwork'];
$coll=$_POST['collaboration'];
$init=$_POST['initiative'];
$self=$_POST['selfregulation'];

$sql= "SELECT * FROM studentlist";

$result=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$stu_dent=$row['Student'];

 $sql1 = "UPDATE studentlist 
    SET responsibility='$resp', organization='$org', independentwork='$ind', 
    collaboration='$coll', initiative='$init', selfregulation='$self' WHERE Student='$stu_dent'";

    $result1=mysqli_query($connect, $sql1);

}





// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result1){



echo $sql1;

echo "Successful";


}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Here's what I get after the the print_r statement...and the echo $sql1

```
   Array
(
    [responsibility] => G
    [organization] => G
    [independentwork] => G
    [collaboration] => G
    [initiative] => G
    [selfregulation] => G
)
UPDATE studentlist 
    SET responsibility='G', organization='G', independentwork='G', 
    collaboration='G', initiative='G', selfregulation='G' WHERE Student='STALEY, PETER DOUGLA'Successful<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

The name is actually the last name in the database, and not the name I tried to update.

Comment: have you tried echoing $sql1 to see what it's ending up as?

Comment: You should use a prepared statement so that the content of your variables cannot break your sql. And to avoid sql injection...

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Since you're learning, now is a great time to learn to properly use [`prepare()/execute()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) in MySQLi so you never start out with bad habits.

Comment: I'm trying to get more than one student. I'm using checkboxes and I want to update the database for each student that has boxes checked...if that makes sense

Comment: @user3006141 Ok that makes sense - I don't see anything in this code that receives those checkboxes though.

Comment: I just echoed $sql1 and it is taking the last student in the list, but all of the records are being updated

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski -- I'm not sure what you mean by "receives the checkboxes" -- I have another page that has the checkboxes with name as responsibility, organization, independentwork...and on this page I am getting those values with $_POST --- am I way out in left field???

Comment: @user3006141 I mean that among all your inputs for `responsibility, organization, etc`, you don't appear to have any which identify a studen. You said "_I want to update the database for each student that has boxes checked_" and I took that to mean you had a list of students with checkboxes, and those selected should be updated, but the code above has no provision for handling student checkboxes (only the properties like responsibility,organization, etc)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski -- I think I understand what you are saying, although I'm not sure if I know how to do that. I've tried using IF ISSET but that still didn't work.

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, but I'm not sure what you're asking...but I will past what I have. I removed the echo student part...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski -- alright, I updated the post. Also I tried this a while back with a different question if you want to see that post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020446/how-do-update-a-specific-row-using-checkboxes

Comment: I see you've echo'd out `$sql1`.  Place `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your script and run it; it will format the full contents of `$_POST` into your output. Look at the browser's page source (ctl-U/cmd-U) and copy/paste the `print_r()` output into your question so we can get a look at what values were sent to the script. It would also help to post the HTML `<form>` which posts to this script.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski -- ok, I've edited it (I really thank you for your help with this...I have been stumped for weeks!!!)

Comment: Echo $sql1 and post it here.

Comment: @keiv.fly -- alright, I've updated with print_r and echo $sql1

Comment: Only the last row is affected. The name does look like that in the database, but that is not the one I tried to update. I tried to update the first row, but the last row was affected.

Comment: It doesn't look like the checkboxes you posted have any relation to any specific user. Perhaps you should generate the HTML form with checkboxes like `<input type='checkbox' name='selfregulartion[{student_id}]' value='E' />`  The values in the `$_POST` would intrinsically carry the student id.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski -- I tried doing what you said I changed it to <input type='checkbox' name='responsibility[{Student}]' value='E'> but the result was that it said array in the database.

Comment: You would need to reorganize some code if you use that method. View `print_r($_POST);` to see the new structure of the array. The checkboxes would be sent as an array, indexed by student id.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski -- could you please give me an example of what you mean...

Comment: @user3006141 In your other question, you are building checkboxes in a loop. Use the student id to differentiate them `echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='students[{$row['Student']}][responsibility]' value='E'></td>";`  That will associate each checkbox with a student. You can loop over them with `foreach ($_POST['student'] as $Student => $properties) { // perform UPDATE with $Student in WHERE... }`   wherein `$Student` holds the id, and `$properties` is an array like `$properties['responsibility'], $properties['organization']`.. Inspect with `print_r($_POST)` to understand its structure.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski -- THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! It took a little fiddling around trying to figure out how to work the array to get the variables set and updated, but it works beautifully. Thank you...!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not run the update query inside the while row your variables will be set to the last value.

Alternatively: get a single row from the db or run the update query inside the while loop to update each row.

Comment: I moved the update inside the while but it's still not working...I feel like I am missing something simple and small.

Comment: We're getting closer. As of right now, it's updating the database with the right information, just the wrong row. It's updating the last row, but I need it to update the selected row.

Comment: Put $result1=mysqli_query($connect, $sql1); inside the while loop

Comment: code has been updated to what I have right now...it's updating the last row as opposed to the row I've selected.

Comment: This is exactly what your code is supposed to do with the info you submit. YOu do not retrieve the list of checked student but select all the students and update each of them.

Comment: so how do you retrieve the list of checked students then??

Comment: you have ckeckboxes, right? each of them has the value of a student. Retrieve the array of the selected checkboxes, do a while on the array and run the update (in other words replace the while from the select with this one). You don't need the select at all